# How to compare a 2D array against a 1D array column-wise?

Tags: numpy

I have two numpy arrays. One of them is 2D while the other is 1D.

```
>>> a = np.arange(0,20).reshape(2,10)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
>>> b = np.full( a.shape[1], 10 )
>>> b
array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
```

I want to compare them column-wise:

1. If the columns elements in `a` is identical to the column element of b, then store row number(s) of a.
2. Else, find the closest matching of `a` to `b` and store the row number(s).

In my example, the output from the comparison should be:

```
[ 1, [0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,1] ]
```

How do I do this in NumPy?

I was thinking of using `np.where( a==b, run a function to get row(s) if same, run another function to get row(s) of diff )`? Is this the way?

Comment: Won't be able to do it in pure numpy, since your result is jagged.

Comment: @user3483203 if the result is not jagged, say we return the mean row, still possible?

Comment: Can you show an example output of what you mean by "mean row"?  If so, it should be possible

Comment: @user3483203 I mean something like `int(stats.mean(0,1))` in python. this will ensure every column will return only 1 value and hence avoid jagged results.

Comment: Why not just store the flattened index so you guarantee only a single value? `mean` could result in duplicates since you lost precision with `int`